# Compiling If statement

Tags: warning-messages, compile, conditional

I'm tring to use `Compile` in the following code, but it gives me an error message that I don't understand:

```
m = Table[i*j, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}];
res = Table[0.0, {i, 1, 2}];
g[a_] := m.a

fun = Compile[{},
  res[[1]] = {{1}, {2}};
  p = Apply[Plus, Flatten[res[[1]]]];
  res[[1]] = If[p > 5, {{1}, {2}}, g[res[[1]]]];
  ]

(*Compile::cplist: res[[1]] should be a tensor of type Integer, Real, or Complex; evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>*)
(*Compile::cplist: {0.,0.}[[1]] should be a tensor of type Integer, Real, or Complex; evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>*)
```

My actual code includes a `Do` loop in the compile but I've removed it here to make the working example simpler. If I take out the first two lines in the `Compile`, then the error disappears:

```
m = Table[i*j, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}];
res = Table[0.0, {i, 1, 2}];
g[a_] := m.a

res[[1]] = {{1}, {2}};
p = Apply[Plus, Flatten[res[[1]]]];

fun = Compile[{},

  res[[1]] = If[p > 5, {{1}, {2}}, g[res[[1]]]];
  ]
```

Where does the error message in the first example come from?

Comment: There are multiple issues with your code. `If` is not the problem and your last `fun` just calls `MainEvaluate`. This [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compile/tutorial/Operation.html) should be helpful.

Comment: And though not well documented, the multiple issues have been well discussed in this site actually. I really suggest you to have a look at those posts tagged with "compile" first. You may also interested in [this page](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_A-K_18.html), though it's based on v4, the 6 principles mentioned therein are still valid today. (The only difference might be that the number of compiliable functions has increased a little. Also see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096/1871) for an up-to-date list.)

Answer (score 3):

To get you started, here are two examples that do work

```
m = Table[i*j, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}];
res = {{{1}, {2}}, {{3}, {4}}};
```

Note that `res` must have the correct rank.

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
```

### Example 1:

```
cfun2 = Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}},
  If[Total@Flatten[x] > 5, {{1}, {2}}, m.x], 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]

CompilePrint@cfun2
```

> ```
>     1 argument
>     1 Boolean register
>     4 Integer registers
>     3 Real registers
>     6 Tensor registers
>     Underflow checking off
>     Overflow checking off
>     Integer overflow checking on
>     RuntimeAttributes -> {}
>
>     T(R2)0 = A1
>     T(I2)3 = {{1, 2}, {2, 4}}
>     I2 = 5
>     I1 = 12
>     I0 = 1
>     R2 = 7.
>     T(I2)2 = {{1}, {2}}
>     I3 = 3
>     Result = T(R2)1
>
> 1 T(R1)1 = Flatten[ T(R2)0, I0]]
> 2   R0 = TotalAll[ T(R1)1, I1]]
> 3   R1 = I2
> 4   B0 = R0 > R1 (tol R2)
> 5   if[ !B0] goto 9
> 6   T(R2)5 = CoerceTensor[ I3, T(I2)2]]
> 7   T(R2)1 = CopyTensor[ T(R2)5]]
> 8   goto 12
> 9   T(R2)1 = CoerceTensor[ I3, T(I2)3]]
> 10  T(R2)4 = Dot[ T(R2)1, T(R2)0, I1]]
> 11  T(R2)1 = CopyTensor[ T(R2)4]]
> 12  Return
> ```

Now you can use `cfun2` in the following way

```
res[[1]] = cfun2[res[[1]]]
```

> ```
> {{5.}, {10.}}
> ```

```
res[[1]] = cfun2[res[[1]]]
```

> ```
> {{1.}, {2.}}
> ```

Or define a helper function

```
fun2[n_Integer] := (res[[n]] = cfun2[res[[n]]];)

fun2[1]
res[[1]]
```

> ```
> {{5.}, {10.}}
> ```

### Example 2:

Make the compiled function `Listable` and use `Parallelization`:

```
cfun3 = Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}},
  If[Total@Flatten[x] > 5, {{1}, {2}}, m.x], 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True]
```

And now

```
res = cfun3[res]
```

> ```
> {{{5.}, {10.}}, {{1.}, {2.}}}
> ```

```
res = cfun3[res]
```

> ```
> {{{1.}, {2.}}, {{5.}, {10.}}}
> ```